# How to save logs from console in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made logger to log from console to screen, something like this:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/49114

```
    void HandleLog(string message, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        if (type == LogType.Assert && !LogErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Error && !LogErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Exception && !LogErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Log && !LogMessages) return;
        if (type == LogType.Warning && !LogWarnings) return;

        string[] lines = message.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

        foreach (string l in lines)
            queue.Enqueue(new LogMessage(l, type));

        if (type == LogType.Assert && !StackTraceErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Error && !StackTraceErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Exception && !StackTraceErrors) return;
        if (type == LogType.Log && !StackTraceMessages) return;
        if (type == LogType.Warning && !StackTraceWarnings) return;

        string[] trace = stackTrace.Split(new char[] { '\n' });

        foreach (string t in trace)
            if (t.Length != 0) queue.Enqueue(new LogMessage("  " + t,type));
    }

      void OnGUI()
    {
        ...
        foreach (LogMessage m in queue)
        {
            switch (m.Type)
            {
                case LogType.Warning:
                    styleText.normal.textColor = WarningColor;
                    break;

                case LogType.Log:
                    styleText.normal.textColor = MessageColor;
                    break;

                case LogType.Assert:
                case LogType.Exception:
                case LogType.Error:
                    styleText.normal.textColor = ErrorColor;
                    break;

                default:
                    styleText.normal.textColor = MessageColor;
                    break;
            }

            GUILayout.Label(m.Message, styleText);
        }

        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

I would like to save logs to db after click save button.
Should I make stringBuilder and append text after enqueuing queue and then write stringBuilder to property or send xml to db?
What is the solution to save not only message text but log type too?

Comment: Yeah, I'd probably make it an object with Message, Stacktrace, LogType and serialize it to json before storing it in the database and then when you get it from DB again, you deserialize it. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html